# JavaFX FullScreen Mode not working

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have a basic JavaFX application, that opens as so

```
public class MyApplication extends Application { 
    private Stage stage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console.setDebug();

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) { 
        // set stage as primary
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setFullscreen(true);      
        stage.show();

        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            public void handle(WindowEvent we) {
                System.out.println("Closing application...");
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Now to change screens i have this function, which i call

```
private void replaceScene(String resource, IControlledScreen controller) {
    try {
        controller.setApp(this);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
        loader.setController(controller);

        Pane screen = (Pane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(screen);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setFullscreen(true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot load resource " + resource);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Example call would be

```
public void goToHome() {
    replaceScene("/fxml/HomeView.fxml", new HomeController());
}
```

Now when i run the application, the first screen is in fullscreen mode, then when i change screens, the screen resizes to window size, then changes again to full screen???  I have tried adding

```
stage.setFullscreen(false);
```

before i call

```
stage.setFullscreen(true);
```

but this does work either.  How can i change screens/scenes without it resizing?

Also is is possible to toggle full screen mode using code, say if i want the user to be able to select full screen mode, can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
private void replaceScene(String resource, IControlledScreen controller) {
try {
    controller.setApp(this);

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
    loader.setController(controller);

    Pane screen = (Pane) loader.load();
    stage.getScene().setRoot(screen);


} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Cannot load resource " + resource);
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, falls over at stage.getScene(), i am guessing because it is null, but used your code and additional check, and now works thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mailkov for his code, nearly worked, but had to change it slightly, to cope with the first screen loading.  This now works using

```
private void replaceScene(String resource, IControlledScreen controller) {
    try {

        controller.setApp(this);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
        loader.setController(controller);

        Pane screen = (Pane) loader.load();

        if (stage.getScene() == null) {
            Scene scene = new Scene(screen);
            stage.setScene(scene);
        } else {
            stage.getScene().setRoot(screen);                   
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot load resource " + resource);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```